# How should I design the classes for a simple CRUD operation in JSF + Hibernate application?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, model-view-controller

I am trying to learn Web Programming using JSF and Hibernate.

I have a table called **mytable** in my MySQL server which has 2 columns: **name, surname**

I also have a MyTable.java which is mapped to this table, it looks like this:

```
// Listing 1
public class MyTable {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public MyTable() {
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

This is mapped via Hibernate, thus this code ( which I have used for testing purposes ) successfully inserts data to mytable:

```
    //Listing 2
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    MyTable myTable = new MyTable();

    myTable.setName("Name");
    myTable.setSurname("Surname");

    session.save(myTable);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And this is what my form on my index.xhtml looks like:

```
// Listing 3
<h:form id="registirationForm" prependId="false">

    <h:outputLabel for="name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="name"></h:inputText>

    <h:outputLabel for="surname">Surname:</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="surname"></h:inputText>

</h:form>
```

**My question is:**

How do I tie my form to the code above?

- Should I make the class MyTable a managed bean, and put a method called **saveRecord** and put the above code in there?
- Should it be mapped to some other class? If so what should it be called? Should I change the name of the current MyTable.java to something like MyTableDao.Java ?

So when the user enters some name, and surname, what method should be called?

Where exactly should I put the code found in Listing 2?

I hope my question is clear, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a basic [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern here. `MyTable` is your model and `index.html` is your view. To tie them together I'd suggest adding a controller class like `RegistrationController`.

The controller would be a managed and the view fields would be using its' properties like this:

```
<h:outputLabel for="name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{registrationController.userName}"></h:inputText>
```

the controller would contain also the save method. You may also add a DAO object like you suggested to separate the persistence details from the buisness logic (which should be in the controller).

So when the user enters name and surname values, these set the properties on the controller (which may be directly translated to your `MyTable` object). Then when save is clicked, a `save` method is called on the controller which uses the 'DAO' to persist 'MyTable' to the DB.

You may also want to look a [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheModel).

Comment: So for example, for each table I have in my application, should I have a tableController.Java ?

Comment: Not really - each controller is rather responsible for a single well defined task. It may use data from a single table, many tables or even non at all. For example the `RegistrationController` may need to access a table with users (to add a new user), permissions  and resources (to grant him default permissions to some resources) and so on.

Comment: It would be more reasonable to assume that for each table you have DTO and DAO objects.

Comment: I've added a tutorial link in the answer.